# my articles publish even when I deselect publish

Tags: nodes

I'm an admin user type with publisher priveges as well. When I save an article, it is always save as "published". Even when I uncheck "published" under "publishing options" it saves as published.

In other words, I make sure "published" is deselected, and when I save and edit the article, the "published" select box is ticked.

My goal here is to save the content as unpublished, but I can't even when manually deselecting "published".

Drupal version 6.30. Fresh install. No whacky modules added.

Comment: What makes you think it's published? Did you try to log out and access it as anonymous user?

Comment: In the "content" view, under the "status" column, the corresponding field says "published". Also when I edit the article, I scroll down and see that "published" is selected. And yes, when I log out and do a search, it is listed in the results.

Comment: I don't think this is a very universal question, it seems specific to your site and setup. I would try normal Drupal troubleshooting starting with removing custom modules then contrib modules, until the problem is resolved. Unless the problem is part of D6 core, which I think is highly unlikely.

Have you checked rules? Maybe there is a rule to always publish an unpublished node.

Comment: I'm not sure where I stated this is a universal question.

Comment: This is what I did to fix the problem: 

1. I disabled all except the core modules. 
2. I then tested to see if I could unpublish content, and I could.
3. I then re-enabled each module until I found the culprit.

In this case, it was the "rules" module.

Comment: Cool! Would be great if you can post your comment as the answer to this question. Even better if you can tell us what is in the rule that acted as the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to fix the problem:

1. I disabled all except the core modules.
2. I then tested to see if I could unpublish content, and I could.
3. I then re-enabled each module until I found the culprit. In this case, it was the "rules" module.

Comment: I've recently experienced this as well recently, but couldn't verify that it was the Rules module. If you can pin it down as a bug it may be good to report it.